# Eclipse doesn't save the Endpoint Template with parameters

Tags: eclipse, endpoint, wso2-esb

I was trying to make use of the Endpoint Template feature of WSO2 ESB and was developing the template from Eclipse.

I'm facing some issues while I code it. The template works fine for the uri part, but when I try to parameterize it for some timeout settings , eclipse doesn't accept it. It strips off all the parameters if I close the template and open it again..

Example below..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template name="TestTemplate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<endpoint name="$name">
    <address format="soap11" uri="$uri"/>
    <parameter name="timeOutDurationParam"/>
    <parameter name="responseActionParam"/>
    <parameter name="errorCodesParam"/>
    <parameter name="initialDurationParam"/>
    <parameter name="maximumDurationParam"/>
    <parameter name="progressionFactorParam"/>
    <timeout>
        <duration>$timeOutDurationParam</duration>
        <responseAction>$responseActionParam</responseAction>
    </timeout>
    <suspendOnFailure>
        <errorCodes>$errorCodesParam</errorCodes>
        <initialDuration>$initialDurationParam</initialDuration>
        <progressionFactor>$progressionFactor</progressionFactor>
        <maximumDuration>$maximumDurationParam</maximumDuration>
    </suspendOnFailure>
    <markForSuspension>
        <errorCodes>$errorCodesParam</errorCodes>
    </markForSuspension>
</endpoint>
```

When I save the above template , close it and open it again in Eclipse, all the parameters are striped off and the below is what remains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<template name="TestTemplate" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<endpoint name="$name">
    <address format="soap11" uri="$uri"/>
</endpoint>
</template>
```

Please suggest if i'm doing something wrong here or is there any setting in eclipse that I need to set?

The version of eclipse i'm using is

[image: Eclipse Version]
Thanks
Kranthi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 confirmed that this issue is a bug in the current eclipse /wso2 plugin as of 04/02/2015.

They are going to release a new version in summer this year which will fix this issue..

Keep waiting..

Thanks
Kranthi